# tensorflow:AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'mul'

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have used tensorflow for ONE day,but there comes some troubles,when I import tensorflow, there would be AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'XXXXXX'

### Environment

I use ubuntu14.04, python2.7, CUDA toolkit 8.0 and CuDNN v5.
And versions of my six and protobuf are:
Name: six
Version: 1.10.0
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requires: 
Name: protobuf
Version: 3.2.0
Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
Requires: six, setuptools

here is my test code:

```html
import tensorflow as tf
a = tf.placeholder(tf.int16)
b = tf.placeholder(tf.int16)
add = tf.add(a, b)
mul = tf.mul(a, b)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Run every operation with variable input
    print "Addition with variables: %i" % sess.run(add, feed_dict={a: 2, b: 3})
    print "Multiplication with variables: %i" % sess.run(mul, feed_dict={a: 2, b: 3})
```

I get this output:

[image]

Is there any problem with the tensorflow installation? or any other problems?

Answer (score 194, accepted):

According to the [tensorflow 1.0.0 release notes](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/RELEASE.md),

> `tf.mul`, `tf.sub` and `tf.neg` are deprecated in favor of `tf.multiply`, `tf.subtract` and `tf.negative`.

You'll need to replace `tf.mul` with `tf.multiply`.

Comment: The documentation says "deprecated", but in reality TF just removed them...

Comment: Yup. They're not deprecated but removed altogether. Thanks for your answer, saved me a tonne of time!

Answer (score 3):

This operation was previously available in 0.x versions. With the [release of TF 1.0 they introduced breaking changes to the API](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/RELEASE.md#breaking-changes-to-the-api). In addition to

> `tf.mul`, `tf.sub` and `tf.neg` are deprecated in favor of `tf.multiply`,
>   `tf.subtract` and `tf.negative`

many other functions were renamed and changed with the following justification:

> Several python API calls have been changed to resemble NumPy more
>   closely.

So a lot of the scripts that you already found on the web or from the books will not work. Good thing is that majority of them can be fixed with their migration [script](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/tools/compatibility). It can be run with `tf_upgrade.py --infile foo.py --outfile foo-upgraded.py`. It will not be able to solve everything (limitations are listed [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/migration)), but will save you a lot of work.

Answer (score 0):

**2.0 Compatible Answer**:

The Commands for **`tf.multiply`**, if we want to migrate from Tensorflow 1.x to 2.x are shown below:

`tf.compat.v1.math.multiply, tf.compat.v1.multiply, tf.compat.v2.math.multiply, tf.compat.v2.multiply`

The Commands for **`tf.subtract`**, if we want to migrate from Tensorflow 1.x to 2.x are shown below:

`tf.compat.v1.math.subtract, tf.compat.v1.subtract, tf.compat.v2.math.subtract, tf.compat.v2.subtract`

The Commands for **`tf.negative`**, if we want to migrate from Tensorflow 1.x to 2.x are shown below:

```
tf.compat.v1.math.negative, tf.compat.v1.negative, tf.compat.v2.math.negative, 
tf.compat.v2.negative
```

See this [Tensorflow Migration Guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate) for more details.

Answer (score -4):

In python-3 use `tf.multiply` instead of `tf.mul`.

Comment: What does this answer add, that the original question doesn't cover?